# Can't shrink drive to create a partition greater than 30gb on windows 7?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have windows 7 and want to install ubuntu alongside it. I have a 1tb hard drive and when I go into disk management it says by c drive (I only have one drive) has 670gb of free space. I want to shrink 132gb for ubuntu but on the window where I choose how much I want to shrink it says "Size of available shrink space in MB: 30885" which is about 30gb. The there is a message at the bottom of the window that says "You cannot shrink a volume beyond the point where any unmovable files are located. See the "defrag" event in the Application log for detailed information about the operation when it was completed."

Does this mean I can only reserve at most 30gb for ubuntu even though I have 670gb of free space on my c drive, is there any way to fix this without reinstalling windows 7?

Comment: It means until you removed the file fragmentation on the system partition, that is indeed the case, you will be limited to 30GB.

Comment: @Ramhound How would I find and remove the file fragmentation on the system partition?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of disk management. Also use [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/) to manage disk more easily graphically.

Comment: @idknuttin - I provided you a link to a duplicate question with an acceptable solution.  Have you tried that acceptable solution?  You remove file fragmentation by def ragging your system partition but that still won't move your page file (among other files) which is fragmented but cannot be used while Windows is running (hence the reason this is a duplicate of an existing question).

Comment: [How can I shrink my Windows partition further than the disk management is allowing?](https://superuser.com/questions/484375/how-can-i-shrink-my-windows-partition-further-than-the-disk-management-is-allowi?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Ramhound, I will try these solutions.